# Spry menu text awful spacing

Tags: html, css, menu, spry

I have a spry menu and in the menu you have sub-menus and the spacing between the numbers is awful. I have changed almost everything in the spry menu `css` but the spacing won't change. I think it has something to do with `padding` but can't confirm that for sure.
So my question is: **Why is the spacing so big between the submenu text?**

[Example Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/index.html).

Here is what the submenu `css` is:

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
margin: 0;
padding-top: .5em;
padding-right: .75em;
padding-bottom: 5em;
padding-left: .75em;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 50%;
z-index: 1020;
cursor: pointer;
width: 83px;
position: absolute;
left: -100em;
border: 0px;
text-align: center;
top: 91px;
height: 307px;
    }
```

I have looked in other question but none of them seem to answer my question. I have read up on spry menus, but no luck there. Maybe someone else can give me some advice.

So let me summarize my question. What do I need to change to have the space of text in sub-menu so that they aren't so far apart?

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting the sub menu elements properly:

It should be something similar to :

```
ul li ul li a{
}
```

or

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li a {
}
```

or

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-right: .75em;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
    padding-left: .75em;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 50%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 83px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100em;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 91px;
    height: 307px;
}
```

Try hovering over one of the submenus, right click and select "inspect" element.  You can see the HTML make up of the controls you are trying to target.

Once you have the right CSS selectors your styling should start working.

Comment: Put your styling code that you posted into one of those selectors. I suggest you put it into the second example. You should see a change in the styling of the submenus.

Comment: what do you mean in one of those selectors?

Comment: Updated examples, try the third one.  CSS selectors are elements/classes/ids that you target in order to override the styling of those elements...  For example if I wanted to style the color of links on the entire website I would target the following CSS selector --- a { color:red; } --- "a" is the CSS selector.

Comment: if i change any of the sub menu names in the css it stops working. no drop down menus

Comment: I didn't ask you to change any of the names in the CSS.  I implied that you should add "li a" to the end of "ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul" that you showed us in your code example.  The resulting selector is: "ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li a".

Comment: ok go to this [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10329732/csc110/index.html) and see that when i change it theres no drop down menu anymore

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46159/discussion-between-apples-and-lowkase)